# -coverprofile excluding untested files from coverage percentage

Tags: go, testing, code-coverage

I'm trying to run a test coverage report on my project which contains several directories (I'm aware this is an unusual setup but it has lots of examples which I want to group together):

```
└── example
    ├── bar
    │   └── main.go
    ├── baz
    │   └── main.go
    ├── foo
    │   ├── main.go
    │   └── main_test.go
    └── qux
        └── main.go
```

However when it run I get some strange output. The coverage percentage seems to only related to the only tested file - not the entire codebase under `example`.

For instance:

```
$ go test -race -v -coverprofile .test-coverage.txt ./...
?       github.com/abcdef/example/bar    [no test files]
?       github.com/abcdef/example/baz      [no test files]
=== RUN   TestSum
--- PASS: TestSum (0.00s)
PASS
coverage: 50.0% of statements
ok      github.com/abcdef/example/foo     1.018s  coverage: 50.0% of statements
?       github.com/abcdef/example/qux    [no test files]
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and whether there's a way I can make it generate a percentage coverage across all files, including any untested files? Otherwise the coverage percentage is completely misleading.

Comment: Is this is what you are looking [for](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24570).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-coverpkg` flag, described thusly:

> Apply coverage analysis in each test to packages matching the patterns. The default is for each test to analyze only the package being tested. See 'go help packages' for a description of package patterns. Sets -cover.

Example:

```
go test -race -v -coverprofile .test-coverage.txt -coverpkg=example ./...
```

This tells go to include package `example` in the coverage stats. Be sure to use the full version of your package name, though.  i.e. `github.com/user/example`